# Instructions per second equation

Tags: cpu-architecture

This should be a simple question.

Say we have a 3.0 gHz processor with a CPI of 1.5 How many instructions per second does it execute? Just thinking logically, it would be the number of cycles per second times the number of instructions per cycle...which is...

3×10<sup>9</sup> cycles/second × 1.5 instructions/cycle = 4.5×10<sup>9</sup> instructions/second

Makes sense. Okay, so this is a question from my book and I look up the solutions just to make *sure* I understand and got it right. Well the solution says that it's:

3×10<sup>9</sup>/1.5 = 2×10<sup>9</sup> instructions/sec

[image: hi]

This answer comes from the clock rate/CPI part, but I am really failing to grasp how...if you sub in clock rate/cpi like this:
(clock cycles/sec)/(instructions/clock cycle), it's basically the opposite of the original equation because you divide cycles by instructions instead of multiplying them...and the units don't even cancel out, you end up with a unit of cycles<sup>2</sup>/instructions×seconds. I have to be missing something totally obvious here/botching basic math, but my pea brain is not getting it.

Comment: Looks like CPI is “cycles per instruction”, not instructions per cycle, thus `CPI = 1 / (instructions per cycle)`, or alternatively if you are dividing by CPI, you can multiply by instructions per cycle instead (and vice-versa).

Comment: Then why does the equation say that IPS = instructions/clock cycle x clock cycles/second, and then suddenly decides to change and use cycles per instruction instead of instructions per cycle? These formulas are supposed to be equivalent, too, yet plugging the same values into them gives different answers...and I'm still wondering about the latter equation producing a bogus unit measurement. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Because most people *do* use IPC or IPS, not CPI.  Most modern CPUs are superscalar and achieve better than 1 instruction per cycle (on average) on typical workloads like SPECcpu.  But a CPI less than 1 causes cognitive dissonance because CPUs can't really do anything in less than 1 cycle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some relatively basic maths here:

```
      Instructions
IPS = ------------
         Second
```

You can multiply something by 1 without changing the result, and since X / X = 1, we can do the following:

```
      Instructions        Instructions   Clock Cycles
IPS = ------------  x 1 = ------------ x ------------
        Seconds             Seconds      Clock Cycles
```

You can then rearrange the fractions as follows:

```
      Instructions   Clock Cycles
IPS = ------------ x ------------
      Clock Cycles     Seconds
```

This gives you the middle part of the provided formula.

Then, given:

```
      Clock Cycles                    Clock Cycles
CPI = ------------  and  Clock Rate = ------------
      Instructions                      Seconds
```

And since 1 / (A/B) = B/A:

```
 1    Instructions
--- = ------------
CPI   Clock Cycles
```

Therefore:

```
       1                 Clock Rate
IPS = --- x Clock Rate = ----------
      CPI                   CPI
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks. Final thing: why does the Clock Rate/CPI equation give a different answer than the middle part of the formula when they're supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: @faezer - in your question you say "3×10^9 cycles/second × 1.5 instructions/cycle", but it's *not* 1.5 instructions/cycle, it's 1.5 cycles per instruction (CPI), so you need to *divide* by 1.5, not multiply.

Comment: Oooooh oh my lord, I'm a dunce. Thank you for clearing this up and bearing with me haha